# MySql select query for same table category and subcategory parent under child

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This question already asked but that not solve my issue.

I have a table given below table name `categories`, here `parent` and `child` are inserted same table. I want to fetch all the child category under parent.

My table:

```
categoryId   categoryName      categorytype  parentCategoryId   status
1            cars                   0              0                1
2            honda city             1              1                1
3            Medical                0              0                1
4            Cancer                 1              4                1
5            bmw                    1              1                1
```

So I want to fetch the data like this Output:

```
categoryId   categoryName        parentCategoryId
1            cars                        0       
2            honda city                  1       
5            bmw                         1      
3            Medical                     0       
4            Cancer                      4
```

What am trying to do is `car` is a `parent` under this all cars name will be listed.

This is the query I tried:

`SELECT * FROM categories c1 left join categories c2 on c2.categoryId = c1.parentCategoryId;`

Comment: looks like your query is missing an `ORDER BY` clause only

Comment: @ProGu: Yes I tried `ORDER by c1.categoryId` but thing is all names not listed properly

Comment: @ProGu: You can see this https://ibb.co/x2PjFWd here `HIV` is a child that is not under `medical` category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one could work

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM categories c1 
LEFT JOIN categories c2 on c2.categoryId = c1.parentCategoryId
ORDER BY COALESCE(c2.categoryId, c1.categoryId), c1.categoryId
```

**Edit**

If root category is fixed `0`, it can be simpler without `JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parentCategoryId = 0 THEN categoryId ELSE parentCategoryId END, categoryId
```